# Display temporary image until an image are loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to display temporary image in an HTML page until original image is loaded. How can I do that?

```
<!-- IMG -->
<img src="original.jpg" temporary-img="temp.jpg"/> <!-- i have no idea how to do that ! -->
```

Comment: is your original image that big that there is a lot of load time?

Comment: I take image from an link. The server are loading slowly ... and i take multiple image in one page...

Comment: You can have another image tag which fetches a small sized image from your local folder.. And on the original image `load` event you can remove the temporary image..

Comment: may be this will help you a bit http://stackoverflow.com/a/13860853/2592042

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the original image is still loaded you can make the following in the HTML:

```
<img src="temp.jpg" id="img" data-original-img="original.jpg"/>
```

If the DOM is loaded, you can use the image, eg. Exchange as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#img').attr('src', $('#img').attr('data-original-img'));
});
```

Or with Plan JS: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can add a background image using CSS.

```
img {
  background: url('temp_image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: @RajshekarReddy it's not stupid... css load the background with a temporary image and when the image is load she's hover the background... it can help OP

Comment: This doesn't work in case the loaded image has a transparent background, in which case you will see the default image in the back :(